# How to remove synced photos from other devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, photos

I have an iPad and an iPhone. When I had both of them sync to iCloud to save storage space, the photos and albums from my iPad went onto my iPhone and vice versa. This messed up both the organization of my photos as well as making it difficult to locate that one specific photo on either device, since I now have much more photos to sort through. I tried to revert the iCloud sync but it refused to revert back to the way things were. Is there any way to remove synced photos from my other device automatically?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) As an aside to your question, have you tried using the search functionality to find/filter your photos? There's a lot of metadata captured in digital photos and you can use this to your advantage.

Comment: I have not tried that, but I am unsure how I could filter the photos out by where they came from.